# Viewing apps that need updating

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

How do I view all apps that need updating on Google play? I'm running Android Kit Kat 4.4.2 on a Samsung galaxy SIII. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Google Play, touch the Menu icon in the upper-left (next to Google Play text), My apps & games, the tab that opens should be called Installed, and anything updating will show an "Update All" button with text in the app description that says "Update".